Is it possible to delete storage elements in total and they don't all delete?
So in a storage mapping, when using functions like clear, remove, clear_prefix, where the logic should remove all of the items in a storage element or ones under a prefix, is it possible to have it not remove all of them? Any possible issues in large removals?
If so, what is a good way to remedy this?
Such as having a backup extrinsic that stores any keys that should be deleted and check if the values within it are and delete if so?
